# C#: How to transform a parent, but only the parent and not the children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, parent-child

(My question could also be rephrased like this: How to ignore an inheriting transformation on a child, with it still being a child.)

I know this sounds counter-intuitive, but maybe there is a good way to do this.

Let me explain my situation so it makes more sense.
Look at the picture below and you can see my character, he is divided into a few gameobjects (since i have been creating the animations from unitys "Animation"-tab.) They all depend on eachother in terms of animation and movement. They also flip when the player needs to flip. When the player turns i want all the bodyparts to move, but when flipping the parts, i explicitly only want everything except the "Head"-object to flip. But that object is in the "Body"-object, which i am "commanding" to flip.. So maybe you would say just to selectively flip the objects inside "Body"? I think i can do that, but i also want to flip the body independantly, but just not one other item in the "Body", which is the head.

I know a few fast solutions like breaking the parent/child link with the body and head, but i still want it as a child if that is possible. I also know you could just track the body's position + an offset to the head without a childlink. But thats not what im looking for.

So is there a way for me to let the head be a part of the body, but still ignore the inheriting onto the head from the rescaling of the body.

Also if you're wondering where the flipping is happening, its in the player script on the player object in the hierarchy. Also if i forgot some information or code you need just ask.

[Hierarchy in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hdSy.png)

Comment: It might be better to map the hierarchy textually in the body of the question.

Comment: Oh okey, was the picture unclear or why? :)

Comment: Check if using an avatar mask could be of use for you, this, if its works for you, will be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You could have another component called "`BodyWithoutHead`", add that to the body and let that be the parent of everything other than the head. Then just flip `BodyWithoutHead` instead of flipping the body.

So your Hierarchy would look like this:

```
- Body
    - BodyWithoutHead
        - (everything other than the head)
    - Head
```